# FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2 java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground().. Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, out-of-memory

this is my doInBackground() in NetworkManager Class

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void...pParams) {

    try {
        // check if connected to Internet
        if(vIsConnectionAvailable()) {
            // create the URL with the target URL specified
            URL url = new URL(vTargetURL);
            // create a HTTP connection to the URL specified
            HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            // set the timeout for the request
            urlConnection.setReadTimeout(REQUEST_TIMEOUT);
            urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(REQUEST_TIMEOUT);
            //add request header
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            // set the HTTP headers for the request.
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(vRequestXML.length()));
            for (HashMap.Entry<String, String> entry : vHttpHeaders.entrySet()) {
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
            }
            // send the request
            DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(vRequestXML);
            dataOutputStream.flush();
            dataOutputStream.close();

            // read the response
            //int bufferSize = 1024 * 100; // 10KB. // Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1000; //
            //int fileSize = 100 * 1024; // 100 * 1024 * 1024 = 100MB.

            //BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
            String inrtermediateLine;
            StringBuffer responseBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            while ((inrtermediateLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                responseBuffer.append(inrtermediateLine);
            }
            // close the bufferedReader
            bufferedReader.close();
            return responseBuffer.toString();
        }
        else {}
 }

   catch (SocketTimeoutException exception) {

        vErrorCode = -2; //Request Timed out
        return null;
    }

    catch (IOException exception) {
        vErrorCode = -3; //Not able to connect to the target server
        return null;
    }
}
```

for xml request i am getting very big response and for small response it is working fine... please help me out of this!! can i use xml file to store response? if then please help how to create xml file for this response..

this is my request format...
 public void vGetPnLData()
    {

```
    String getReportXML = "<ENVELOPE>.....";
    HashMap<String, String> httpHeaders = new HashMap<String, String>();

    // set the headers
    httpHeaders.put("ID", MainActivity.vReportName);
    httpHeaders.put("SOURCE", "EA");
    httpHeaders.put("TARGET", "TALLY");
    httpHeaders.put("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
    httpHeaders.put("Accept-Encoding", "identity");
    httpHeaders.put("TARGETACCOUNTINTERNALID", MainActivity.vAccountInternalId);
    httpHeaders.put("TARGETCOMPANYNAME", MainActivity.vConnectedCompany);

    // create an object NetwrokManager class. This is an AsyncTask which handles everything related to sending the HTTP requests
    NetworkManager networkMgrObj = new NetworkManager(MainActivity.vReportName, MainActivity.vTrbUrl, getReportXML, httpHeaders);
    // execute the AyncTask
    networkMgrObj.execute();
}

public static void getPLDataResponseCallback(String pResponse) {

    // parse the response to get the report data
    String pLSheetData[][] = XMLParser.getPLBackupReportData(pResponse);

    if (pLSheetData == null)
    {
        // show the error message
        //Error = "No Data found. Please check report in Tally";
    }
    else
    {....}}
```

this gives me following error....

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
Process: com.visionsolutionsindia.visiontallyapp, PID: 5335
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)                                                                                           
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 57283554 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 51MB until OOM
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer(AbstractStringBuilder.java:95)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:146)                                                                                           
at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:219)                                                                                           
at com.visionsolutionsindia.visiontallyapp.NetworkManager.doInBackground(NetworkManager.java:103)
at com.visionsolutionsindia.visiontallyapp.NetworkManager.doInBackground(NetworkManager.java:39)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)                                                                                            
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: Memory allocation failes ( see Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 57283554 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 51MB until OOM ... ). Any chance to split you package into smaller peaces?

Comment: u know how to split?? @KimKulling

Comment: someone please  provide me answer....

Answer (score 0):

Try to separate the incoming response into a bundle of **responseBuffer**-packets and handle the incoming lines of the packets:

```
// Set an upper limit for responsebuffer size
static const int BLOCKSIZE = 1024;
while ((inrtermediateLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    responseBuffer.append(inrtermediateLine);
    if ( responseBuffer.lenght() > BLOCKSIZE ) {
        // implement your response ahndling here!
        handleResponse(responseBuffer);
        responseBuffer.delete(0, responseBuffer.length());
    }
}
```

In your code you are increasing the response-buffer until there is no more memory to allocate. Special on an embedded device this is a dangerous strategy to handle big data-blobs.

Comment: The place wher you need to implement you own handling of the response, which was received.

Comment: can you please help me to implement.. i dont have knowlwdge about handleResponse() as im not getting it in android....